# Understanding docker port mapping output of docker ps

Tags: docker

If I run my docker container with:

`docker run -it -p 5432:5432 postgres-words`

Output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                   STATUS         PORTS                                               NAMES
512416e853e1   postgres-words   "docker-entrypoint.s…"  Up 5 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   busy_chatelet
```

But with `docker run -it -p 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 postgres-words`,
`docker ps` reports:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                     STATUS         PORTS                            NAMES
44131e2fa6ff   postgres-words   "docker-entrypoint.s…"     Up 4 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   festive_chandrasekhar
```

My question is that what is the significance/meaning of extra `:::5432->5432/tcp` in the first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:::5432->5432/tcp` is referring to IPv6. `::` in IPv6 has the same meaning as `0.0.0.0` in IPv4, because you can omit zeros in an IPv6 address and replace them with `::`. It is also called the [unspecified address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.2). For reference you can also look at this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket).